# Why is my HTML h1 element spanning two lines when it has plenty of space to use one?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my website and the heading (`h1`) text is taking up two lines, which it has space for but shouldn't as it has plenty of space to just take up one line. I want it to only span one line, and I'm wondering why it isn't doing that? Thanks!

The text I'm taking about is the `<h1>`, `id="welcome"`, content `Welcome to my website!`.

---

P.S. if your going to run the code snippet make sure to do it full screen to see the effect.

Here's my Code:

```css
li {
 display: inline-block;
}

ul {
 float: right;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
 top: -45px;
}

nav li a:link {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: times;
 font-size: 24px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 3px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: black;
}

nav li a:visited {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 color: white;
}

nav li a:active {
 color: black;
 border-color: black;
}

nav {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 130px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=search] {
 font-size: 16px;
}

#searchbox {
 float: right;
}

#logo {
 width: 200px;
 font-family: arial;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-size: 26px;
}

#logo_jeff, #logo_arries, #logo_website {
 margin: 0px;
}

#logo_jeff {
 letter-spacing: 35.5px;
}

#logo_arries {
 letter-spacing: 11px;
}

#logo_website {
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}










body {
    background-image: url("../pictures/jeff_skiing.jpg");
    background: red;
 min-height: 500px;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

aside {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 width: 170px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
}









#main_content {
 width: 1000px;
 min-height: 600px;
 display: block;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 position: relative; top: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#here_you_can_learn {
 font-size: 47px;
 color: gray;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

#welcome {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 110);
 font-size: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 130px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#down_arrow {
 height: 50px;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
}

#most_frequent {
 width: 600px;
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#m_f_heading {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}



#m_f_show_more {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}


#recent_activity {
 width: 375px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#r_a_heading {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_body {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_show_more {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_show_more_link:visited {
 color: black;
}

#r_a_show_more_link:hover {
  color: gray;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

#r_a_show_more_link:active {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Home | Jeff's Website</title>

<link href="styles/main_navigation.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/body.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main_content.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>


<body>

<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
 <nav>
  
   <form action="" id="searchbox">
   <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
   <input type="submit" value="Search!">
  </form>
  
  <div id="logo">
   <h1 id="logo_jeff">JEFF</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_arries">ARRIES</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_website">WEBSITE</h1>
  </div>

  <ul>
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>


<!--Welcome to jeff's website-->

<div>
 <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to my Website!</h1>
 
 <p id="space_filler"></p>
 
 <a href="#here_you_can_learn">
 <img src="pictures/down_arrow.png" id="down_arrow"/>
 </a>
</div>

<!--right side nav-->

<aside>
 <p>this is aside</p>

</aside>


<!--Main Content-->

<div id="main_content">
 <h2 id="here_you_can_learn">Here you can learn about me and my adventures!</h2>

<!--Most Frequently visited pages: on left side of page-->
 <div id="most_frequent">
  <p id="m_f_heading">Most frequently visted pages!</p>
  
  
  
  <a href=""><p id="m_f_show_more">Show More</p></a>
 
 </div>
 
<!--Recent Activity: on the right side of page-->
 <div id="recent_activity">
  <p id="r_a_heading">Recent Activity</p>
  
  
  <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
  
  
  <a href="" id="r_a_show_more_link"><p id="r_a_show_more">Show More</p></a>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Look into the `feed-line` element - it's empty, so it's hard to notice, but it's a `float` that's smack in the middle of your issue.

Comment: Unrelated to your technical question, but for semantic and SEO purposes you should only have a single `h1` tag on your page. If you need to break it up further, use spans and apply styles to those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being  caused by the floats on your search-box and on your `ul` menu.  If you're going to use floats you should clear them, although in general, floating things just causes more problems than it fixes.

Add a clear-fix for your `header`:

```
header::after {
   clear: both;
   content: '';
   display: table;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/napoleon/pen/XXOrdJ)

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use `header { overflow: hidden }` or `nav { overflow: hidden }` as a clearfix?

Comment: what should I use instead of floats?

Comment: I would wrap `#searchbox` and your `ul` menu in a parent div.  Take the relative positioning off of the `ul` and take the floats off of #searchbox and your `ul`.  Then if you absolutely position the `#searchbox`, you can fix the positioning of the `ul` by giving `#logo` and the wrapper div widths and putting `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper div.  Make sure that `#logo` and your wrapper div both have `display: inline-block`.  I hope that helps.  Here's a link to a CodePen: http://codepen.io/napoleon/pen/rxPyQR?editors=0100

Comment: @Jeremy Yes.  But `overflow: hidden` is a much more hacky type of clearfix as it can cause other unwanted behavior.

Comment: Tried what you said in comment, for some reason my `#searchbox` is all the way to the right of the page, not just to the right of the nav bar, any suggestions?  As a side note, when you say "and putting overflow: hidden on the wrapper div."  do you mean the `ul` or `#searchbox` wrapper?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` should go on the `#searchbox` wrapper.  I forgot to mention that you need to put `position: relative` on `#searchbox` wrapper as well.  If the parent doesn't have `position: relative`, putting `position: absolute` on the `#searchbox` will position it relative to the document.

Comment: Got that, now the `#searchbox`/`Searchbox div` doesn't show, any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, `#searchbox div` had `overflow: hidden;` which, when removed the `#searchbox` appeared.

Comment: I'm having the problem of some blank space at the top of the nav bar, above the `#logo` and `#searchbox`, as you can see in my other SO post (link below), which apperently the `position: absolute;` is supposedly causing the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375955/why-is-there-space-above-an-element-that-appears-to-have-no-margin-or-padding

Answer (score 2):

Try using "display: inline-block;" at the end of your 'welcome' CSS.

```
#welcome {
border: 1px solid #999;
color: rgb(0, 0, 110);
font-size: 100px;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 130px;
padding: 0px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Works, but not the best.  It is usually undesirable to give a header element `display: inline-block`.  The correct solution is just to clear the float that's causing the mess as @JordanMulder pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding instead of margin.

here is the code

```
#welcome {
border: 1px solid #999;
color: rgb(0, 0, 110);
font-size: 100px;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Below code after padding are css3 that helps in cross browser compatibility

Comment: I found that didn't fix the issue of the text spanning two lines when it only needs and has plenty of room to span one, did you misunderstand my original question?