# Why is there space above an element that appears to have no margin or padding?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I'm wondering why the elements in my nav bar appear to have blank space above them?  I've checked the margin and padding and there doesn't seem to be an issue, but there is a large space above my `#logo` and `#searchbox` which is messing up my layout, how can I get rid of the space above the elements?

Thanks a lot!

---

Here's my Code:

```css
li {
 display: inline-block;
}

ul {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#main_nav, logo {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

nav li a:link {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: times;
 font-size: 24px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: black;
}

nav li a:visited {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 color: white;
}

nav li a:active {
 color: black;
 border-color: black;
}

nav {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 130px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=search] {
 font-size: 16px;
}

#searchbox {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}

#searchbox_div {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

#logo {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 font-family: arial;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-size: 26px;
}

#logo_jeff, #logo_arries, #logo_website {
 margin: 0px;
}

#logo_jeff {
 letter-spacing: 35.5px;
}

#logo_arries {
 letter-spacing: 11px;
}

#logo_website {
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}










#main_content {
 width: 1000px;
 min-height: 600px;
 display: block;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 position: relative; top: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#here_you_can_learn {
 font-size: 47px;
 color: gray;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}


#welcome {
 text-align: center;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 110);
 font-size: 100px;
 margin: 0;
padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
}

#down_arrow {
 height: 50px;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
}

#most_frequent {
 width: 600px;
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#m_f_heading {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}



#m_f_show_more {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}


#recent_activity {
 width: 375px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#r_a_heading {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_body {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_show_more {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_show_more_link:visited {
 color: black;
}

#r_a_show_more_link:hover {
  color: gray;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

#r_a_show_more_link:active {
  color: black;
}










body {
    background-image: url("../pictures/jeff_skiing.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 500px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

aside {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 width: 170px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Home | Jeff's Website</title>

<link href="styles/main_navigation.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/body.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main_content.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>


<body>

<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
 <nav>
  <div id="searchbox_div">
   <form action="" id="searchbox">
    <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
    <input type="submit" value="Search!">
   </form>
  </div>
  
  <div id="logo">
   <h1 id="logo_jeff">JEFF</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_arries">ARRIES</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_website">WEBSITE</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="main_nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>


<!--Welcome to jeff's website-->

<div>
 <h2 id="welcome">Welcome to my Website!</h1>
 
 <a href="#here_you_can_learn">
 <img src="pictures/down_arrow.png" id="down_arrow"/>
 </a>
</div>

<!--right side nav-->

<aside>
 <p>this is aside</p>

</aside>


<!--Main Content-->

<div id="main_content">
 <h2 id="here_you_can_learn">Here you can learn about me and my adventures!</h2>

<!--Most Frequently visited pages: on left side of page-->
 <div id="most_frequent">
  <p id="m_f_heading">Most frequently visted pages!</p>
  
  
  
  <a href=""><p id="m_f_show_more">Show More</p></a>
 
 </div>
 
<!--Recent Activity: on the right side of page-->
 <div id="recent_activity">
  <p id="r_a_heading">Recent Activity</p>
  
  
  <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
  
  
  <a href="" id="r_a_show_more_link"><p id="r_a_show_more">Show More</p></a>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Canonical rule for debugging CSS placement. USE A BROWSER DEVELOPER TOOLSET.  Firefox and Chrome come with excellent toolsets that will show you exactly how components are being laid out and where each bit of space comes from.  Stop, do not pass GO, learn to use these tools before doing anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<nav>` element has a padding of `10px`.

**EDIT:** The absolutely positioned search form seems to be causing the problem. I made the following changes and the space went away:

```
#searchbox_div {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#searchbox {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 26px;
    float: left;
}
#main_nav{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 4em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: maybe that's the problem

Comment: Tried, but if I do that it still has the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I asked the question you see the link to below, which the answer was don't use floats. Is there any other way I could use to position it without floats that still makes the space go away? Link to post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353649/why-is-my-html-h1-element-spanning-two-lines-when-it-has-plenty-of-space-to-use

Comment: I disagree with the comment in your other question that floats cause more trouble than absolute positioning. Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal flow of the page, which can often cause strange behavior, like overlapping elements for example. But YMMV.

Comment: Is there a way to position it without `float`s or `position: absolute;`?     I don't see where they say " floats cause more trouble than absolute positioning. ", I see "although in general, floating things just causes more problems than it fixes.".

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you`re not using a css reset. A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline.

In case you didn’t know, every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain amount of padding to almost everything. Ever wondered why Submit buttons look different in every browser?

Obviously this creates a certain amount of headaches for CSS authors, who can’t work out how to make their websites look the same in every browser.

Using a [CSS Reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/), CSS authors can force every browser to have all its styles reset to null, thus avoiding cross-browser differences as much as possible.

Also, sometimes if I have a problem with blank spaces, I run the html all together so there are no blank spaces between the tags. To make it look neat, I insert carriage returns in the middle of the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to need to reset/normalize your css as that

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

Comment: Tried, not working, any more advice?  Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

By default, most browsers have an 8px or so margin that is built in or "Added" to the page style. The super easy way to eliminate this is through CSS. Simply use:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  }
```

You can also add:

```
padding:0;
```

If it's still giving you problems!

Comment: Tried, not working, any more advice?  Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

The `<nav>` element is configured to have 10 pixels of padding on all sides.

Comment: Which element are you taking about?

Comment: The answer is visible now.  It took me an edit to get it to render correctly.